# A question regarding ❋166.44 in Whitehead & Russell's Principia Mathematica

Tags: logic, math-history, foundations

In the first step of *Dem*, I wonder how $\Sigma ‘\times P^{;}Q$ is transformed into $\Sigma‘ \Sigma^;(P \overset{\downarrow}{.,})\dagger^; Q$. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojgzn.png
Thanks,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is inspired by [a previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/903824/119110) in which @Mauro discovered the similarities between ✳113.44 and ✳166.44 and suggested that their dems are analogous to each other.

$×α‘β$ is convenient because it is viewed as the descriptive function $×α$ taking $β$ as its input.

By ✳38.11, $ ×α‘\beta=α×β $

By ✳113.1, $ α×β=s‘α\underset{,,}{\downarrow}‘‘β $

By ✳37.101, $s‘α\underset{,,}{\downarrow}‘‘β=s‘α\underset{,,}{\downarrow}ϵ‘β$. In other words, $s‘α\underset{,,}{\downarrow}ϵ$ is also a descriptive function.

Now we can see that the two descriptive functions are equivalent: $×α=s‘α\underset{,,}{\downarrow}ϵ$

Given $k$ as a class of $β$'s, when we want the descriptive function $×α$ to go inside $k$ and perform $×α$ on every each of $k$'s members, we write $×α‘‘k$. (See ✳37.01)

Thus, $(\times \alpha)‘‘k = s‘‘\alpha \underset{,,}{\downarrow} \epsilon‘‘k=s‘‘ \alpha \underset{\overset{\textbf{,,}}{\ }}{\downarrow}‘‘‘k$.

*I.e.* First let $α\underset{,,}{\downarrow}ϵ$ go in and take each of $k$'s member as input, then let $s$ go into the resulting class and operate on each of the newly transformed members.

This explains the first step of 113.44's Dem: $s‘(×α)‘‘k=s‘s‘‘α\underset{ ,,}{\downarrow}‘‘‘k$.

---

Now, cardinal $s$ is analogous to ordinal $Σ$, and cardinal $R‘‘$, $Rϵ$, $‘‘$ are analogous to ordinal $Σ;$, $Σ†$ and $;$ respectively. Like $×α‘β$, $×P‘R$ is a descriptive function of $R$.

By ✳38.11, $×P‘R=R×P$

By ✳166.1, $R×P=Σ‘P\underset{.,}{\downarrow}^;R$

By ✳150.1, $Σ‘P\underset{.,}{↓}^;R=Σ‘(P\underset{.,}{↓}†)‘R$, in other words, $Σ‘(P\underset{.,}{↓}†)‘R$ is a descriptive function of R.

Now we can see, the two descriptive functions are equivalent:

$×P=Σ‘(P\underset{.,}{↓}†)$ ------- (1)

Given $Q$ as a relation of relations,$ ×P;Q$ performs $×P$ on every term of $Q$'s field. In virtue of (1), $×P;Q$ is the same as $(Σ‘(P\underset{.,}{↓}†));Q$, which is to perform $Σ‘(P\underset{.,}{↓}†)$ on every each of Q's field, which is equivalent to perform $P\underset{.,}{\downarrow}†$ on each of Q's field, then perform $Σ $on each of the newly transformed field members, i.e. $Σ^;(P\underset{.,}{↓})†^;Q$. This explains the first step of 166.44 Dem, $Σ‘×P;Q=Σ‘Σ^;(P\underset{.,}{↓})†;Q$

Answer (score 6):

It is very hard to "disentangle" this formula.

We have to start with the LHS of $✳166.44$ :

> $\Sigma‘ \times P^{;} Q$.

The first step is to apply the "transformation" $✳166.1$ : $Q \times P = \Sigma‘P \underset{\overset{\textbf{.,}}{\ }}{\downarrow}^{;} Q$.

---

*Note*

In the following steps I'll use "$\downarrow$" in place of "down-arrow with dot & comma". Alas! "downarrow" is already used in *PM* for the *couple* $x \downarrow y$.

---

Applying $✳166.1$ to $\Sigma‘ \times P$ we get :

> $\Sigma‘ P \downarrow^{;} \Sigma‘^{;} Q$.

Now we need $✳38.11$ to "play with" $\downarrow$ [see $✳38.11$ in vol.I, page 313 :

> $x \downarrow‘ y = \downarrow y‘x = x \downarrow y$

and the example with "$\cap$" : $\alpha \cap \beta =\cap \beta‘ \alpha$. This is so because we can "read" the intersection of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as a function $\cap \beta‘$ "applied to" $\alpha$.]

Assuming that we have correctly applied it (see the *Addendum* for details), we have :

> $[\Sigma‘(\Sigma‘ P \downarrow)^{;}]^{;} Q$.

We finally apply $✳150.1$, which again is "quite simple" : $S^{;}Q = S \dagger Q$, to get :

> $[\Sigma‘(\Sigma‘ P \downarrow) \dagger]^{;} Q$.

---

*Addendum*

We have to consider (thanks to George...)  $✳116.44$, which is the cardinal counterpart of $✳166.44$ (please, note the same number after the dot ...) :

> $(s‘k) \times \alpha = s‘(\times \alpha)‘‘k$

Forgetting the "switch" of LHS with RHS, it has clearly the same "form" of :

> $\Sigma‘ \times P^{;} Q = (\Sigma‘ Q) \times P$.

The first step in the proof of $✳116.44$ is an application of $✳113.1$ :

$\beta \times \alpha = s‘ \alpha \underset{\overset{\textbf{,,}}{\ }}{\downarrow} ‘‘\beta$ Def ["downarrow with two commas"].

This, in turn, is the correlate of $✳166.1$ :

$Q \times P = \Sigma‘P \underset{\overset{\textbf{.,}}{\ }}{\downarrow}^{;} Q$ Def.

Now, back again to the proof of $✳116.44$ : we apply $✳113.1$ to the RHS [where $s‘$ is the "$\beta$" and $\alpha$ is the "$\alpha$"], to get :

> $s‘(\times \alpha)‘‘k = s‘ \alpha \underset{\overset{\textbf{,,}}{\ }}{\downarrow}‘‘s‘ ‘‘k$.

Here we need some transformation of the above RHS [see the text of *PM* page 114 and George's answer] :

> > $s‘s‘‘ \alpha \underset{\overset{\textbf{,,}}{\ }}{\downarrow}‘ ‘‘k$

Now, we can exploit the analogy between $✳166.44$ and $✳116.44$, "mimicking" the steps of $✳116.44$ :

> $s‘(\times \alpha)‘‘k = s‘ \alpha \underset{\overset{\textbf{,,}}{\ }}{\downarrow}‘‘s‘ ‘‘k = s‘s‘‘ \alpha \underset{\overset{\textbf{,,}}{\ }}{\downarrow}‘ ‘‘k$

with something like :

> $\Sigma‘ \times P^{;} Q = \Sigma‘ P \underset{\overset{\textbf{.,}}{\ }}{\downarrow}^{;} \Sigma‘^{;} Q = \Sigma‘ \Sigma‘ P \underset{\overset{\textbf{.,}}{\ }}{\downarrow}^{;;}Q$

and then replace one of the two "$;$" with the "dagger" ($\dagger$), according to $✳150.1$.

Comment: Thanks, @Mauro. See below. Now I can picture this transformation. But I still don't know how the magic of ✳38.11 works. I think the precedence is $\Sigma‘(\times P^;Q)$

Comment: @GeorgeChen - But I'm still puzzled; if I follow the above comment,  assuming that $Q \times P$ and $\times P^{;}Q$ are "equivalent", the formula boils down to : $\Sigma‘(Q \times P) = (\Sigma‘Q) \times P$. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Almost a volume later, I'm just beginning to appreciate 38.11. The power of 38.11's magic is that it converts $\beta \times \alpha$ into a form that can take a class as arguments. When $\times \alpha$, with the help of $‘‘$, takes a class $k$ as argument, it performs $\times \alpha$ on each of $k$'s member without having to enumerate every each of them. This is one of the techniques PM uses to make infinity accessible to human knowledge. $;$ is just the ordinal counterpart of $‘‘$

Comment: $R\times P$ is analogous to $\beta \times \alpha$; $\times P ^;Q$ is analogous to $\times \alpha‘‘k $ where k is a class of classes and $Q$ is a relation of relations

Comment: Sorry, @Mauro. I can't accept your answer as it is, but the final answer is totally inspired by your line of thought.

Comment: If I picture this transformation, I have to mention these terms individually, which is impossible in the case of infinite fields. Thus ✳38 comes to the rescue. In ✳182 summary another similar symbol was introduced and the merits of ✳38 was made clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an illustration for 113.44:

Suppose $k=\{ \beta, \gamma, \delta, ... \}$

Then

$(\times \alpha)‘‘k$

$ = \{\times \alpha ‘\beta, \times \alpha‘\gamma, \times \alpha‘\delta, ...\} $

$=\{\beta \times \alpha, \gamma \times \alpha, \delta \times \alpha, ...\}$

$=\{s‘\alpha \underset{,,}{\downarrow}‘‘\beta, s‘\alpha \underset{,,}{\downarrow}‘‘\gamma,s‘\alpha \underset{,,}{\downarrow}‘‘\delta,...  \}$

$=s‘‘\{\alpha \underset{,,}{\downarrow}‘‘\beta, \alpha \underset{,,}{\downarrow}‘‘\gamma,\alpha \underset{,,}{\downarrow}‘‘\delta,...   \} $

$=s‘‘\alpha\underset{,,}{\downarrow}‘‘‘\{\beta, \gamma,\delta,...   \} $

$=s‘‘\alpha\underset{,,}{\downarrow}‘‘‘k$

Or,
For any $\beta\in k$

$\times \alpha‘\beta = \beta \times \alpha = s‘\alpha \underset{,,}
{\downarrow}‘‘\beta= s‘(\alpha \underset{,,}{\downarrow})_{\epsilon}‘\beta$

Then

$(\times \alpha)‘‘k=s‘‘(\alpha\underset{,,}{\downarrow})_\epsilon‘‘k=s‘‘\alpha\underset{,,}{\downarrow}‘‘‘k$

Comment: I see ... But (as in the proof of $✳116.44$) why there is no need of $✳38.11$ ??? Or we have to presume that the appeal to $✳38.11$ in the proof of $✳166.44$ is mistaken ?

Comment: I added another line. Yes, 38.11 is implicit in pretty much every step.

Comment: $\times \alpha ‘\beta = \beta \times \alpha $ that's 38.11

Comment: Thanks agian; but how we can "reconcile" $\times \alpha ‘ \beta = \beta \times \alpha$ with $\beta \times \alpha = s‘ \alpha \downarrow ‘‘ \beta$ to get the expected transformation ?

Comment: I like your way of thinking, @Mauro. I can "see" the step now.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/905841/119110

Answer (score 0):

If $S^;P$ is like $S‘‘C‘P$ in an order similar to $P$, then in picture:

> $S‘R$-----**$S^;P$**------$S‘T$
>
> $S\uparrow$------------------$\overset{\smile}{S} \downarrow$
>
> $R$----------**$P$**---------$T$

---

Given $R=Q‘T$,When the correlator is $ \times P$, then $\times P^;Q$ can be pictured like this (from bottom up):

> $R$----------------**$\huge{Q}$**--------------$T$

$\uparrow$

Take $(P\underset{.,}{\downarrow}\dagger) $ out of $(P\underset{.,}{\downarrow}\dagger)^;Q$'s field we have $Q$'s field.

$\uparrow$

> $P\underset{.,}{\downarrow}^;R$-----**$\huge{(P\underset{.,}{\downarrow}\dagger)^;Q}$**---------$P\underset{.,}{\downarrow}^;T $

$\uparrow$

Take $\Sigma $ out of $\times P ^;Q$'s field, we have $(P\underset{.,}{\downarrow}\dagger)^;Q$'s field. Thus,
$\times P^;Q =\Sigma^;((P\underset{.,}{\downarrow}\dagger)^;Q) $

$\uparrow$

> $\Sigma‘P\underset{.,}{\downarrow}^;R$-----**$\huge{\times P^;Q}$**------$\Sigma‘P\underset{.,}{\downarrow}^;T $

||

> $R\times P$--------**$\huge{\times P^;Q}$**----------$T \times P $

$\uparrow$

$  \times P$

$\uparrow$

> $R$----------------**$\huge{Q}$**--------------$T$

Comment: Sorry, I cannot grasp it. Assuming you corrected reading as : $Σ‘(\times P^{;}Q)$ if we apply $✳166.1$ we get : $\Sigma‘P^{;}Q \underset{\overset{\textbf{.,}}{\ }}{\downarrow}^{;} \Sigma‘$. In this case, we can use $✳38.11$ to "flip around" the "downarrow" but only in one way which moves it to the left, like in $\alpha \cap \beta = \cap \beta‘ \alpha$...

Comment: OK I can see. We can leave out the first $\Sigma $ and work on $×P^; Q $ which is like Q by the correlater $×P $

Comment: Shown by the first step from the bottom.